# Changing span text of a class

Tags: javascript

I am having troubles changing text of a span class on a website.
I've tried many things but nothing is happening.
What i want to do is to change from value 0 to 245.

```
<td>Coins: <span class="myCoins">0</span></td>
```

This is link to the compiler [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dVBRm/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery 
$('.myCoins').text(252)